# Why child element corners with border-radius: inherit; doesn't align with parent's

Tags: css, border

Given the code below:

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <p class="child-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A, distinctio? Pariatur voluptas officia placeat dolores, quam soluta laborum commodi voluptates cum quos illum labore eum nihil, perspiciatis nobis et reiciendis?</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  border: 7px solid #888;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: lime;
}

.child-text {
  border-radius: inherit;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, tomato, purple);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Result: https://codepen.io/nikitahl/pen/PMYqVy

Can someone please explain why there is a space around the corners of the child element in this case, why are they not aligned? Also, this issue is present only when the `border` property is set on a parent.

And is there a fix except for setting `overflow: hidden` on a parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply setting your childs `border` to a lower px value will solve this - or as I've done below, you can remove `border-radius: inherit`.

Your issue was you applied a 20px `border-radius` on both elements, and as the child element was smaller than the parent, it means the `border-radius` appears more harsh, as the `<p>` tag was smaller - causing them to both be unaligned.

[Updated CodePen](https://codepen.io/Kxrl/pen/qeWZeX)

[MDN - Border Radius](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius)

**EDIT:**

If you wanted to negate the `overflow` property - the only other way I can think of if you needed to keep your parent properties as they are would be to set the `border-radius` of the child to the same scale of radius as the parent - in this case about 12px as seen below.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  border: 7px solid #888;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: lime;
}

.child-text {
  border-radius: 12px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, tomato, purple);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p class="child-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A, distinctio? Pariatur voluptas officia placeat dolores, quam soluta laborum commodi voluptates cum quos illum labore eum nihil, perspiciatis nobis et reiciendis?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, but the parent still has the `overflow: hidden` property. Is there a way to avoid adding this property?

Comment: I guess that's the only way to go. But upon investigating I guess the correct value for the child element `border-radius` property would be `calc(20px - 7px)`, where 20px is the `border-radius` and 7px is the `border-width` of the parent, so it would result in 13px. What do you think?

Comment: I think that's absolutely correct @nikitahl - makes sense! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this adding css to only `child-text`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.child-text {
  border: 7px solid #888;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, tomato, purple);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p class="child-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A, distinctio? Pariatur voluptas officia placeat dolores, quam soluta laborum commodi voluptates cum quos illum labore eum nihil, perspiciatis nobis et reiciendis?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: That solution is not applicable to my case.